# Store emoticons in mysql?

Tags: ios, mysql, xcode, laravel

In previous version `xcode (7.0.1)`, it can save emoticons look like `⚽️❤️`, my database, table and column all set `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`, `mysql` version `5.5.46`.

With version `xcode (7.2.1)`, it show `???????`.

By the way, this still working:

```
INSERT INTO `table_name` (`col_name`) VALUES ('⚽️❤️');
```

Query log from IOS:

```
INSERT INTO `table_name` (`col_name`) VALUES ('\ud83d\ude1c');
```

Just log `$request (Laravel 5.2.16)`, I get:
[image]

How to fix it? Thanks!